# 2 independent poisson random variables probabilities and 2 different proofs

Tags: probability, random-variables

[image: The exercise I need to solve]

So, in the above exercise I was wondering if I could get some help with :

2.1 - I was told moment generating functions could help me prove that, but I can't get it
2.2 - I don't get how to start with this. Is it implying that the sum is binomially distributed?

Thanks!

Comment: The conditional distribution of $X$, **given** that $X+Y=n$, is indeed binomial.

Comment: The most basic approach to 2.1 works. Surely you have already computed the distribution of the sum of two independent discrete random variables with known distributions, how did you do that?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Andre : thanks , i'll try googling and understand binomial. Did : I'm sorry if the questions sound terrible but its a Senior University type of course and I'm approaching the whole statistics and probability subjects without previous base knowledge. When you refer "basic approach" do you mean using the formula for a poisson probability of 1 random variable and try to do algebra on it until it works?  Thanks

Comment: I asked my previous question for a reason, unfortunately you choose to ask me another one instead of answering it. This cannot be very productive.

Comment: @Did Ok I'll play. To answer your question : I didn't.

Comment: Then, *how to compute the distribution of the sum of two independent discrete random variables with known distributions* should be the question you ask yourself, no? (I did not write "should be the question you ask on MSE" because the answer is in every textbook you might have around you.)

Comment: Please do not use the tag (poisson-geometry) for questions related to Poisson random variables. The two are unrelated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 2.2: $$P(X=m|X+Y=n)={P(X=m \cap X+Y=n)\over P(X+Y=n)}$$
but $P(X=m \cap X+Y=n)=P(X=m\cap m+Y=n)=P(X=m\cap Y=n-m)$.  And since $X$ and $Y$ are independent this is the same as the product $P(X=m)P(Y=n-m)$.  So now you have
$$P(X=m|X+Y=n)={P(X=m)P(Y=n-m)\over P(X+Y=n)}$$

That should get you going, but let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Hey Arthur thanks for that. Yep, that helped a lot, I proceeded with replacing everything with probability function and simplifying and I was able to reach proof.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I solved 2.1 :

[image]

Thanks everyone

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

To solve 2.3 I thought about it like this :

When talking about independent random variables it is said that P(X|Z)=P(X), since when solving 2.1 and 2.2 I showed that P(X|Z) and P(X) are not equivalent or equal then they are not independent. Meaning they depend on each other.